# It does not print out the task that was entered base on user input c++

Tags: c++

The problem I have right now is that it doesn't print out the input base on user input. Example:

After I have inserted the day that I want to add a schedule to my calendar and the task I input is "C++" but nothing came out of the program just break. I expect it to print "C++" The problem I believe it should be at this part:

```
for (;;) {
  cout << "You task: " << endl;
  string sunday;
  if (!getline(cin,sunday) || sunday.empty())break;
  sunday_task.push_back(sunday);
  for (int i = 0; i<sunday_task.size(); i++){ // This part does not work
      cout << sunday_task[i] << endl; // This part does not work
    }
```

I have tried many answers but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>


using namespace std;



string login() {
  start:
  cout << "Please login to access your account" << endl;
  cout << "Please enter your username or email: " ;
  string username;
  getline (cin,username);
 if (username == "duxton"){
   cout << "Please enter your password:";
   string password;
   getline (cin, password);
   if (password == "password") {
     cout << "You have successfully login" << endl;
     char choice;
     cout << "\n\nChoose one of the choice below:\n"
          << "a. Add a schedule to your calender\n"
          << "b. View your schedule for the month\n"
          << "c. Exit\n\n";


      //Get the choice
     cout << "Insert Option:";
     cin  >> choice;



  // potential to be use in struct
  vector <string> sunday_task ;


  string days;


  switch (choice)
  {
  case 'a': cout <<"Sunday   Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday" << endl;
  cout << "Which day would you like to insert task to? " << endl;
  cout << "Insert day : " ;
  cin >> days;
  if (days == "Sunday" or "sunday")
  {
    for (;;) {
      cout << "You task: " << endl;
      string sunday;
      if (!getline(cin,sunday) || sunday.empty())break;
      sunday_task.push_back(sunday);
      for (int i = 0; i<sunday_task.size(); i++){
          cout << sunday_task[i] << endl;
        }

    }


  }
            break;
       case 'b':    cout << "View calender" << endl;


             break;
       case 'c':    break;


       default:
         cout << "Input Error!";

       }


     }
     else {
       cout << "Login failed" << endl; goto start;
     }

      }
   else { cout << "Login failed" << endl; goto start;}

   cin.get();


 }

 int main(){
     login();

     return 0;
 }
```

my output is:

```
Please login to access your account
Please enter your username or email: duxton
Please enter your password: password
You have successfully login 

Choose one of the choice below:
a. Add a schedule to your calender
b. View your schedule for the month
c. Exit

Insert Option:a
Sunday   Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday
Which day would you like to insert task to?
Insert day : sunday
You task: c++
```

^^ After this part I expect it to print out "C++"

I'm sorry as I'm new to StackOverflow, I hope I have explained it clearly and given sufficient amount of information.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DSC You can produce a nicer link by using `[mcve]`, which turns into: [mcve]

Comment: @melpomene Thanks. Wasn't aware of that. I saved the page as a bookmark.

Comment: @DSC there is a whole bunch of these magic links, try also `[edit]` or `[ask]`

Comment: Your example misses the definition of `sunday_task` and the braces are inconsistent. Please provide full example.

Comment: We're not trying to be difficult, and don't worry if you don't know how to use SO, you'll learn. But seriously, do read through the instructions in [mcve], start from scratch, throw out all the parts that are unrelated to your problem (you can put them in later) and get a reduced version that shows only your problem while still being compilable and runnable (with all the `#include`s and `main` left in).

Comment: And try to come up with a better description of your problem than 'it does not do as what I expect it to do'. We don't know what it did do (tell us) and what you expected (tell us too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrelated problem: `string login()` as I mentioned in the neighboring comments, if you promise a string, you have to return one, otherwise bad things will happen. Or change the function to void. Always compile with warnings enabled, try to fix them.

Your problem is that
`cin >> string_variable` and `cin >> char_variable` leave an unprocessed newline sitting around in `cin` so the next time you do a getline, you get an empty string.
Put something like `string temp; getline(cin, temp);` after `cin  >> choice;` and after `cin >> days;` to eat that extra newline.

Comment: Thanks for the unrelated problem part it solve that error.

After i tried putting it it shows me this error: 
no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, char&)'
       getline(cin,choice);

Comment: @DuxtonLim Try `istream::ignore` to skip the extra newline character.